# Nesting Structure Comparisons

Tags: python, recursion, nested, comparison

I'm trying to write Nesting Structure Comparison with recursion. Seems pretty basic but doesn't work: when I compare `len(original)` and `len(other)` they're different, but it doesn't `return False`. Why?

```
def same_structure_as(original,other):
    if type(original) != type(other) or len(original) != len(other):
        return False
    for i in range(len(original)):
        if type(original[i]) != type(other[i]):
            return False
        if type(original[i]) is list and type(other[i]) is list:
            same_structure_as(original[i],other[i])
    return True

print (same_structure_as([1,[1,1]], [2,[2]]))
```

Comment: Apart from indentation there is an issue with your recursion call to `same_structure_as`: return is missing, so independent of daughter result True is returned.

Comment: Thank you, now it should look better... Could you please elaborate on missing return?

Comment: re-read the question. during your second loop, since [1,1] and [2] are both type: lists, they will return "true". You need to fix the for loop.

Comment: They have different lengths.... I check both for type and length.

Comment: Yes, but even after it returns "False" on your 2nd loop, it will return to your first loop's for loop and then return "True". To help you debug, replace ```return False``` and ```return True``` with ```return print("False")``` and ```return print("True")```

Comment: Solved it. Guidot gave a hint. I just needed "return" before recursion

Answer (score 2):

As commented, your code did not consider the recursion result. I corrected it and used a combined loop instead of the repeated cumbersome indexing. (I still don't like the multiple return construction). Note that you don't compare simple values in the loop, so an else part for the list type comparison is still needed. Otherwise this works as expected:

```
   def same_structure_as(original, other):
       if type(original) != type(other) or len(original) != len(other):
           return False
       for org_val, other_val in zip(original, other):
           if type(org_val) != type(other_val):
               return False
           if type(org_val) is list and type(other_val) is list:
               if not same_structure_as(org_val, other_val):
                   return False
       return True

   print (same_structure_as([1,[1,1]], [2,[2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Scratching my original answer, but this is more related to your nested array length.

`len([1,[1,1]])` will have a length of 2. It will not count the inner nest items. Therefore, comparing this nested list with other list will pass on your if check.

Comment: I tried. It returns True than len(original) != len(other).

Comment: length of [1,[1,1]]  is 2,  and length of [2,[2]]  is 2 as well. 

doing length on both list will be the same, since it counts the outer list items of the nested array.

Comment: After first recursion it compares [1,1] and [2] (second elements of arrays)....lengths are different and it should return False.